# Testing RX java

Tags: android, unit-testing, rx-java, rx-android

```
   public void getTerms(boolean showDialog) {
  service.getTermsFromServer().subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(new SingleSubscriber<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(String value) {

            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(value);
                JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
                String content = data.getString("content");
                String id = data.getString("id");
                if (showDialog) {
                    ***signUpView.showDialog(content, id)***;
                } else {
                    agreeTerms(id);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Throwable error) {
            Log.e(getClass().getName(), "Error : " + new Gson().toJson(error.getStackTrace()));
            ErrorCheck.processError(error, gson, signUpView);
        }
    });

}
```

Please help me in testing this code. I have attached the method which i want to test. Here I want to verify that showDialog method gets called

Attaching the Unit test code also

```
@Test
public void testGetTermsCalled(){
    String terms= "{\"data\":{\"id\":\"67f07c7a482542\",\"content\":\"<h3>Part of the test</h3>\",\"timestamp\":1484768675815,\"timestampFormatted\":\"2017-01-18T19:44:35\"},\"metadata\":null,\"version\":{\"id\":\"v1\",\"versionStatus\":\"candidate\",\"message\":null}}";
    TestSubscriber<String> testSubscriber = new TestSubscriber<>();
    signUpService.getTermsFromServer().just(terms).subscribe(testSubscriber);
    signUpPresenter.getTerms(true);
    Mockito.verify(signUpView).showDialog("<h3>Part of the test</h3>","67f07c71-1707-4b7a-a168-d7d05a482542");

}
```

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use `RxJavaPlugins.setInitIoSchedulerHandler` and `RxAndroidPlugins.registerSchedulersHook` to specify your own `TestScheduler`, then use its `advanceTimeBy` method to make some time pass, then verify that the expected calls happened.